# Component using "Suspense" showing spinner on consequent loads (changing its height for a moment)

Tags: reactjs, pagination, tabs, paginator, react-suspense

I'm rendering a number of items, where each individual item uses the same component:

[image: A single component using Suspense]

This component internally uses **Suspense**:

```js
<Suspense fallback={<Spinner />}>{children}</Suspense>
```

Whenever I click the paginator, a new set of items is rendered. Each of the items uses the same "Suspensed" component.

**Problem:** Each of the instances shows a **fallback** (spinner, loader) for a moment, and only then its content.

Since the fallback has constant height, this changes the height of the parent container, which makes the whole page jumping around:

[image]

I'm wondering how could I fix this? Basically, I'd like to avoid the new set of items to collapse due to showing the fallback. Sure, showing the fallback on initial load is fine, but I don't think the already loaded component (dynamically imported code) should show it on consequent pages.

I tried using [React.startTransition](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#starttransition), but that didn't help.

I also checked with components which are not lazily loaded, and everything works fine (parent height remains constant).

Thanks for help!

---

**Update: I came up with a "poor man's fix":**

1. wrapping children inside 2 divs
2. ResizeObserver monitoring the height of the inner div and setting the same height to the outer one, but in *debounced* fashion (100ms later)

Resources:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver/ResizeObserver
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-debounce

Note: You'll probably need to mock ResizeObserver in your Jest tests: https://github.com/que-etc/resize-observer-polyfill/issues/50#issuecomment-488064120